# nested smart pointer operator->

Tags: c++, pointers, nested, operator-keyword

I have my own smart pointer class realization.

```
template<typename Pointee>
class SmartPtr {
private:
    Pointee* _pointee;
    SmartPtr(SmartPtr &);
public:
    explicit SmartPtr(Pointee * pt = 0);
    ~SmartPtr();
    SmartPtr& operator=(SmartPtr&);
    operator Pointee*() const { return *_pointee; }
    bool operator!() const { return _pointee != 0; }
    bool defined() const { return _pointee != 0; }
    Pointee* operator->() const { return _pointee; }
    Pointee& operator*() const { return *_pointee; }
    Pointee* get() const { return _pointee; }
    Pointee* release();
    void reset(Pointee * pt = 0);
};

template<typename Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>::SmartPtr(SmartPtr &spt) :_pointee(spt.release()) {
    return;
}

template<typename Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>::SmartPtr(Pointee * pt) : _pointee(pt) {
    return;
}

template<typename Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>::~SmartPtr() {
    delete _pointee;
}

template<typename Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>& SmartPtr<Pointee>::operator=(SmartPtr &source)
{
    if (&source != this)
        reset(source.release());
    return *this;
}

template<typename Pointee>
Pointee * SmartPtr<Pointee>::release() {
    Pointee* oldSmartPtr = _pointee;
    _pointee = 0;
    return oldSmartPtr;
}

template<typename Pointee>
void SmartPtr<Pointee>::reset(Pointee * pt) {
    if (_pointee != pt)
    {
        delete _pointee;
        _pointee = pt;
    }
    return;
}
```

In main.cpp I can do this:

```
SmartPtr<Time> sp1(new Time(0, 0, 1));
cout << sp1->hours() << endl;
```

***Time*** it's my own class for testing. It has method *hours()* which show in console count of hours I set in constructor.

But when I want have nested smart pointers I need do this:

```
SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Time>> sp2(new SmartPtr<Time>(new Time(0,0,1)));
cout << sp2->operator->()->hours() << endl;
```

How can I do nested smart pointers but without using *operator->()*? Just like this:

```
SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Time>> sp2(new SmartPtr<Time>(new Time(0,0,1)));
cout << sp2->hours() << endl;
```

It can also be not only nesting level 2, but any for example:

```
SmartPtr<SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Time>>> sp3(new SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Time>>(new SmartPtr<Time>(new Time(0, 0, 1))));
```

And we should use:

```
cout << sp3->hours() << endl;
```

Instead of:

```
cout << sp3->operator->()->operator->()->hours() << endl;
```

Comment: Why should one use nested smart pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `operator->` one time to reach down several layers, unless you specialize `Pointee` to recognize `SmartPtr` types so `operator->` can be written recursively.

Otherwise, just use your `operator*` instead to clean up all those nested `operator->()` calls:

```
cout << (*(*(*sp3))).hours() << endl;
```

Or

```
cout << (*(*sp3))->hours() << endl;
```

Comment: Is it possible to recognize that Pointee it's my SmartPtr?

Comment: @Max template specialization